# Laravel how to get current user rank by points?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to get current user rank by points. Example. I'm getting all total users count by:

```
$userCount = User::count();
```

I have users table with points column.
USERS table:

```
USER ID | USERNAME | POINTS
1         USERA       32.25
2         USERB       2.25
3         USERC       -12.25
```

I need to take selected user rank by his points.

**Updated:**
My blade to show user profile:

```
        public function show($slug)
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = User::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
        if (! $user->isActivated()) {
            $this->alertInfo(trans('app.access_denied'));
            return;
        }
        $user->access_counter++;
        $user->save();
        $this->title("Player $user->username profile");
        $this->pageView('users::show', compact('user'));
    }
```

Route file:

```
ModuleRoute::context('Users');
    
ModuleRoute::resource('users', 'UsersController', ['only' => ['index', 'show', 'edit', 'update']]);
ModuleRoute::get('players/{slug}', 'UsersController@show')->name('users.show');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the position for the currently authenticated `User`, you can do the following:

```php
// get all users and order them by the `points` field in descending order
$usersByPoints = User::orderBy('points', 'desc')->get();

// search through your users to find the record where
// the name of the user record matches that of the autneticated user
$position = $usersByPoints->search(function ($user, $key) {
    return $user->name == auth()->user()->name;
});

// add 1 to the poisition as it will be zero indexed
return $position + 1;
```

**update**

Based on your comment, lets define a route in `web.php`:

```php
Route::get('/user', UserProfileController::class);
```

Create the `UserProfileController` in your `app/Http/Controllers` directory using artisan (or manually if you prefer):

```sh
php artisan make:controller UserProfileController
```

Inside of this controller, define a single function called `__invoke()` which will be called by Laravel when someone accesses the `/user` route and add the code from above:

```php
public function __invoke()
{
    $usersByPoints = User::orderBy('points', 'desc')->get();

    $position = $usersByPoints->search(function ($user, $key) {
        return $user->name == auth()->user()->name;
    });

    return view('user.profile', ['position' => $position + 1]);
}
```

In the above the `return view()` specifies the blade view to render when someone accesses the `/user` route and passes the `position` property to the view.

Create the blade view at `resources/views/user/profile.blade.php`. You can then access the `$position` property as follows:

```html
Your position is {{ $position }}!
```

**update 2 - doing it on the DB**

MySQL does not have the concept of a `row number` function like other DB engines, however, the above query can be performed on the DB rather than in memory using PHP for those that care:

```
$position = (int) (DB::select(
    'select (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) as `position` from users, (select @row_number:=0) as t where id = ? order by points desc',
    [auth()->user()->id]
)[0])->position;

return $position + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. How can i use it on blade? Create public function? I'm new on laravel and again thanks for answer!

Comment: @Erikas I have updated my answer for you.

Comment: still nothing. i updated my first post with blade.

Comment: I would not recommend using `search` as you are searching on a Collection, let the DB do that as PHP is going to be really slow compared to DB, when you can use a simple query to do that.

Comment: @Erikas You don't put funcions in your blade file, read my answer again. If it doesn't make sense I suggest you do some reading on the [basics of Laravel](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch).

Comment: @matiaslauriti The OP does  not want the `User` the the `max` points. The OP wants wants the DB row number for the `User` when the `Users` are ordered by `points`. That is not a simple query in MySQL. Read the question again, carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a simple SQL query, in this case `Eloquent`.

```php
$user = User::max('points');
```

That should return the `user` with the highest point. [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i need to take USER rank, not username who has MAX points.

Comment: Can you define that as it is not clear ? What do you mean with `User` rank ? You are getting a `User` back...

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need to take out selected user rank by points. Example: USER1 has 1000 points and USER2 has 100 points. So USER2 rank is #2. So i need to take out rank position that: '#2' :)

Comment: So, someone selects "User 10" and you want to show what rank it is ?